# Python. How to sum up all even integers in a list?

Tags: python

I'm completely new to the subject and I want to ask how to sum up all even integers in a list (without using functions (I haven't studied them yet))?
For example:

```
myList = [1, 3, 5, 6, 8, 10, 34, 2, 0, 3]
```

I create for loop

```
for i in myList:
  if x % 2 ==0:
  # I'm stuck here
```

How to store these values to calculate the sum?

Comment: Did you try using a variable?

Comment: You said `for i in myList` and then you started using x in `x % 2`. either use i or use x. Next you need a variable that you can add x to if this condition is true.

Answer (score 7):

Using a generator expression:

```
>>> myList = [1, 3, 5, 6, 8, 10, 34, 2, 0, 3]
>>> sum(num for num in myList if not num%2)
60
```

Using `filter()`:

```
>>> myList = [1, 3, 5, 6, 8, 10, 34, 2, 0, 3]
>>> sum(filter(lambda x: not x%2, myList))
60
```

Using a manual loop:

```
>>> myList = [1, 3, 5, 6, 8, 10, 34, 2, 0, 3]
>>> result = 0
>>> for item in myList:
...     if not item%2:
...             result += item
...
>>> result
60
```

Answer (score 5):

Sorry, I just had to golf this. Maybe it'll teach someone [the ~ operator](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/expressions.html#unary-arithmetic-and-bitwise-operations).

```
>>> myList = [1, 3, 5, 6, 8, 10, 34, 2, 0, 3]
>>> sum(~i%2*i for i in myList)
60
```

Found another one with the same length:

```
>>> sum(i&~i%-2for i in myList)
60
```

Comment: OK...I'll bite...`~i % 2`?  I can see that the `i % 2` evaluates to `False`, which then evaluates to `0 * i`, but the `~`?

Comment: @DougR. Nah, the `~` has the highest precedence of those three. One effect it has is that it changes the number's parity, which is very handy here.

Comment: I may not understand it, but it's always nice to see some bitwise voodoo. :)

Comment: Once I read the unary operator page, it was blindingly obvious what you were doing.  Thanks!

Comment: @DougR. So I already did teach someone that operator... nice :-)

Comment: @TigerhawkT3 Yeah, but that would be unacceptably long and trivial :-P

Comment: True; it takes a snippet and balloons its size by 150% (2 characters to 5)... and it doesn't even involve twiddling any bits! :(

Comment: @TigerhawkT3 I just added another, how do you like that one?

Comment: PEP8 doesn't explicitly say that you should have at least one space around keywords, so the new one is good!

Answer (score 1):

You need to store the result in a variable and add the even numbers to the variable, like so:

```
>>> myList = [1, 3, 5, 6, 8, 10, 34, 2, 0, 3]
>>> result = 0  # Initialize your results variable.
>>> for i in myList:  # Loop through each element of the list.
...   if not i % 2:  # Test for even numbers.
...     result += i
... 
>>> print(result)
60
>>>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can filter out all non-even elements like so

```
my_list = [1, 3, 5, 6, 8, 10, 34, 2, 0, 3]
even_list = filter(lambda x: x%2 == 0, my_list)
```

and then sum the output like so:

```
sum(even_list)
```